# MySQL set default value to other columns from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have three tables as shown below, **artist**, **stage** and **event**. I am trying to figure out if there is any way to set the default value of **event.cost** like this **(artist.popularity * stage.reputation)**.
Is it possible to do this or do I have to set the cost value manually when inserting?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A calculated column cannot reference a column from other table (all it sees are the values on its own table row).

Instead, you could use a trigger that fires for each insert on `event` and that assigns a default value to `cost` from the other table/columns:

```
delimiter |
create trigger trg_event_price
before insert on event
for each row
begin
    if new.cost is null then
        set new.cost = 
            (select popularity from artist where id = new.artist_id)
            * (select reputation from stage where id = new.stage_id)
        ;
    end if;
end
|
delimiter ;
```

With this trigger in place, you can then ignore column `cost` when `insert`ing into `event`, and let the trigger handle it:

```
insert into event (artist_id, stage_id) values(1, 5);
-- "cost" will be computed from the popularity of artist 1 and the reputation of stage 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly u have to define the id of both the table artist and stage as primary key ans the while entering the data in events table u can import the two id values for each using foreign key tutorialspoint

SQL - Foreign Key
Advertisements

Previous PageNext Page
A foreign key is a key used to link two tables together. This is sometimes also called as a referencing key.

A Foreign Key is a column or a combination of columns whose values match a Primary Key in a different table.

The relationship between 2 tables matches the Primary Key in one of the tables with a Foreign Key in the second table.

If a table has a primary key defined on any field(s), then you cannot have two records having the same value of that field(s).

Example
Consider the structure of the following two tables.

CUSTOMERS table

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS(
   ID   INT              NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR (20)     NOT NULL,
   AGE  INT              NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS  CHAR (25) ,
   SALARY   DECIMAL (18, 2),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
ORDERS table

CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
   ID          INT        NOT NULL,
   DATE        DATETIME, 
   CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID),
   AMOUNT     double,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
If the ORDERS table has already been created and the foreign key has not yet been set, the use the syntax for specifying a foreign key by altering a table.

ALTER TABLE ORDERS 
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS (ID);